# Setting an attribute value in XML

Tags: c#, xml, configuration-files

i am trying to change the count attribute within instances, the xml is below

```
<ServiceConfiguration xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" serviceName="" osFamily="1" osVersion="*"      
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ServiceHosting/2008/10/ServiceConfiguration">
<Role name="WebRole1">
    <ConfigurationSettings>
       <Setting name="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" />
    </ConfigurationSettings>
    <Instances count="1" />
    <Certificates />
</Role>
</ServiceConfiguration>
```

I have tried the following that i saw in another question, but i get the error "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

```
changeConfigXDoc.Root.Element("ServiceConfiguration").Element("Role").Element("Instances").Attribute("count").Value=ChangeInstanceText.Text;
```

Comment: I think you can get rid of the `.Root.Element("ServiceConfiguration")`, assuming your `changeConfigXDoc` is representative of the above XML. Or just try removing the `.Root`.

Comment: Tried both ways and i continue to get the error "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

Comment: Try separating your Root.Element chain out to separate variables to help identify where the Object not set reference might be.  This may help you identify the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should take the *namespace* into consideration

```
XNamespace ns = XNamespace.Get("http://schemas.microsoft.com/ServiceHosting/2008/10/ServiceConfiguration");
changeConfigXDoc
    .Element(ns + "ServiceConfiguration")
    .Element(ns + "Role")
    .Element(ns + "Instances")
    .Attribute("count").Value = ChangeInstanceText.Text;
```

Or

```
XNamespace ns = XNamespace.Get("http://schemas.microsoft.com/ServiceHosting/2008/10/ServiceConfiguration");
changeConfigXDoc
    .Descendants(ns+"Instances")
    .First()
    .Attribute("count").Value = "666";
```

Answer (score 1):

Root is the `<ServiceConfiguration />` node, try doing this instead:

```
changeConfigXDoc.Root.Element("Role")
                     .Element("Instances")
                     .Attribute("count").Value = ChangeInstanceText.Text;
```

Add [these extension methods](https://github.com/ChuckSavage/XmlLib/blob/master/XElementExtensions.cs) and then try this,

```
changeConfigXDoc.Root.Set("Role/Instances/count", ChangeInstanceText.Text, true);
```

Comment: tried this and i am still getting the "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."